# Attempt to rotate bar graph failed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to rotate my bar graph, which can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/jq9qftLL/

Here's what I have so far:

```
        var canvas = d3.select("#canvas");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

//rectangle values
var values = [{
    cValue: Math.abs(xthree),
    color: '#A0F'
}, {
    cValue: Math.abs(xtwo),
    color: '#FA0'
}, {
    cValue: Math.abs(xone),
    color: '#0AF'
}, {
    cValue: Math.abs(xzero),
    color: '#AF0'
}];

//var colours = ['#A0F', '#FA0', '#0AF', '#AF0'];

var yOffset = 0;

//create scale
//yRange2 = d3.scale.linear().range([canvas.height - MARGINS.top,
//MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0, 10]);

//yrange2- imp-Set domain to be set to biggest number
yRange2 = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([MARGINS.bottom, canvas.height - MARGINS.top]);

//Process the data

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    var datum = {

        value: yRange2(values[i].cValue),
        colour: values[i].color,
        y: 0,
        x: yOffset

    }

    yOffset += (canvas.height - MARGINS.top - datum.value);

    data.push(datum)
}

//setup y
yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yRange2)
    .tickSize(5)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSubdivide(true);

canvas.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
    .call(yAxis2);

var bars = canvas.selectAll('rect').data(data)

var cumValues = 0;
bars
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr("class", "myBars" + function (d) {
        return d.colour;
    })
    .attr({
        height: 30,
        y: 60,
        x: function (d) {
            return d.value - d.y;
        },
        width: function (d) {
            console.log(canvas.width, MARGINS.left, d.value);
            return canvas.height - MARGINS.top - d.value;
        }
    })
    .style({
        fill: function (d) {
            return d.colour
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to be displaying right, as can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/ehv6fb1L/

I know that the graphing system works differently than standard graphs, so I was wondering if I could get some help on what I was doing wrong, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jq9qftLL/1/) all you needed to do was to invert height& width, x & y… now you have to just fix the axis!

```
bars
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
        height: 30,
        y: 60,
        x: function (d) {
            console.log(d);
            return d.value - d.y;
        },
        width: function (d) {
            return canvas.height - MARGINS.top - d.value;
        }
    })
```

Comment: Well, one of the issues that I was having is that the axis is above the graph despite being given the bottom orientation. I also have an issue where for some reason the bars are much longer than they should be, both of which can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/ehv6fb1L/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ehv6fb1L/2/

orientation for the axis gives the bottom placing to the ticks not the axis itself :) 
for the placing of the axis, which now is called yAxis, you have to fix the translate you apply to it, for the width of the bars check the width attribute! (before it was still using canvas height and margin top, now I put margin left and canvas width but don't really know what graph I'm looking at so I can't tell if the size is correct now)

Comment: Using your advice, I've set the axis to work, but the bars still seem to be too long even with the height to width adjustment. I've set the values to 3,2,1, and .5 in here to make it easier to see: http://jsfiddle.net/ehv6fb1L/3/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error is the value that you push as value in the for cycle for the datum, you're using range values as values for the bars, like here in the inspector it's visible: http://jsfiddle.net/ehv6fb1L/5/ however I'm still not sure how the graph should look like so can't really fix that as you want, if you could provide a sketch that would be easier, but I'm pretty sure that if you double check the datum cycle and the width values you'll be able to figure it out (use console.log like as much as you can!)

Comment: No, it's okay actually, since I figured it out by looking at some more texts about this kind of stuff, but thanks anyway